# PHP loop needs to be incremented by more than one each time. How can I exit out of the loop when condition is met?

Tags: php

I want to combine three php arrays by taking one entry and placing it underneath the other, like so:

```
while ($i <= $no)
{
        $results[$i] = $blah[$i];
        $i++;
        $results[$i] = $thing[$i];
        $i++;
        $results[$i] = $something[$i];
        $i++;
}
```

However the problem with this is $no can be exceeded as I need to increment $i three times in each loop.

End result:

```
array (size=12)
  1 => 
    array (size=4) (from $blah)
  2 => 
    array (size=4) (from $thing)
  3 => 
    array (size=4) (from $something)
  4 => 
    array (size=4) (from $blah)
```

...this needs to continue until the size of $no is met

Comment: There's almost certainly a much better way of achieving this. Can you edit the question to show/describe the end result you want?

Comment: The loop will still exit, even if `$no` is exceeded, but is it permissible to exceed `$no` even during a loop iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple tought, can't you do something like this???

```
   while ($i <= $no)
        {
                $results[$i] = $blah[$i];
                $i++;
                if($i > $no){ break;}
                $results[$i] = $thing[$i];
                $i++;
                if($i > $no){ break;}
                $results[$i] = $something[$i];
                $i++;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [`break` statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php). You may also want to [append](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) to the result array, instead of specifying a specific index:

```
$results = array();
while ($i <= $no) {
    $results[$i] = $blah[$i];
    $i++;
    if ($i > $no) break;
    $results[] = $thing[$i]; // just append
    $i++;
    if ($i > $no) break;
    array_push($results, $something[$i]); // append with array_push
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: That returns 3 results inside a new array key (up to $no). This means there is 3 times as many results that I need. (edit: sorry not sure how to get this code looking right)
`array (size=10)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=4) (from $blah)
      1 => 
        array (size=4) (from $thing)
      2 => 
        array (size=4) (from $something)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=4) (from $blah)`

Comment: Oh, you're right. Removed the short version. The long one should be exactly what you need though.

Answer (score -1):

Why not simplify:

```
$results = array_push($blah, $thing, $something);
// appends the arrays together
```

or

```
$results = array_merge($blah, $thing, $something);
// merges arrays together
```